# Implications of `mount --make-private /`

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

Currently, `/` has shared mount propagation:

```
# findmnt -o TARGET,PROPAGATION /
TARGET PROPAGATION
/      shared
```

I am considering changing it to `private` to enable `mount --move` to work on filesystems mounted under `/mnt` and `/media`.

(I want to use `mount --move` rather than the unsafe `umount --lazy`)

Without `/` being `private`, `mount --move` will complain with something like:

```
# mount --move /mnt/mountpoint /mnt/moved
mount: /mnt/moved: bad option; moving a mount residing under a shared mount is unsupported.
```

1. Why is `/` `shared` by default?
2. What are the implications of changing `/` to be `private`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The propagation flag is changed by `systemd`. From `man 7 mount_namespaces`:

> systemd(1) automatically remounts all mount points as MS_SHARED on system startup. Thus, on most modern systems, the default propagation type is in
>   practice MS_SHARED.

From https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/core/mount-setup.c#L406

```
  /* Mark the root directory as shared in regards to mount propagation. The kernel defaults to "private", but we
     * think it makes more sense to have a default of "shared" so that nspawn and the container tools work out of
     * the box. If specific setups need other settings they can reset the propagation mode to private if
     * needed. Note that we set this only when we are invoked directly by the kernel. If we are invoked by a
     * container manager we assume the container manager knows what it is doing (for example, because it set up
     * some directories with different propagation modes). */
    if (detect_container() <= 0)
            if (mount(NULL, "/", NULL, MS_REC|MS_SHARED, NULL) < 0)
```

The implications depend on your particular use cases. I think that most programs will continue to work. However, your change will be overwritten on reboot.

You can read more in the comment from Lennart Poettering in https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=739593

Here is a part of it:

> b) If you patch systemd to go back to MS_PRIVATE for the root dir, you
>     disable propagation to containers, and nobody can opt-in to it anymore
>      for their specific namespace.
>
> Advantage: you don't have to patch those few programs which
>      currently assume the root dir is MS_PRIVATE and don't disassociate
>      things.
>
> Disadvantage: the apps are still broken for those who switch to
>      MS_SHARED for /. You hence only cover the usecases where people do
>      not dissassocitate. You break the usecase where people want the
>      propagation to tkae place.